# Web Api Post data always null xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android

I have visual studio 2017 with following Xamarin version in system.

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.6.1
>   VisualStudio.15.Release/15.6.1+27428.2002 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.7.02556
>
> Xamarin 4.9.0.749 (9b0fce36d) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin Designer 4.10.58 (cee1369d0) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.
>
> Xamarin.Android SDK 8.2.0.15 (HEAD/22d97e153) Xamarin.Android
>   Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.
>
> Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 11.8.0.20 (1c6f300) Xamarin.iOS and
>   Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support. And i have
>   create simple Xamarin android with some .net class library add as
>   reference.

I have try to post some data using xamarin application, but always get null value in webapi.

Below WebApi code in c#

```
 public class DataPostController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public string Post(CSVItem data)
        {

            // CSVData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CSVData>(json);
            try
            {
                string error = string.Empty;
                if (data != null)
                {


                    error += ImportService.clsGlobal.AddItem(data.SerialNumber, data);

                }
                error = string.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "-1" : error;
                return error;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return ex.Message;
            }
        }

        public string Get()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }
```

Calling post method using xamarin app

```
   CSVItem item = GetItems();
    var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}?", "http://myurl.com", "api/DataPost");
                            string sContentType = "application/json"; // or application/xml

                            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "cHRlc3Q5OnB1bXB0ZXN0OUAxMjM0NTY=");
                            var oTaskPostAsync = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(item.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType));
                            var res = oTaskPostAsync.ContinueWith((oHttpResponseMessage) =>
                           {
                               Task<string> r1 = oHttpResponseMessage.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                               var strResult = r1.Result;

                               // response of post here
                               Pt9Log.WriteLog("HistoryDownload PostCSV end. StatusCode" + oTaskPostAsync.Result.StatusCode.ToString());
                               Pt9Log.WriteLog("HistoryDownload PostCSV end. Result===" + oTaskPostAsync.Result.ToString());

                               Pt9Log.WriteLog("HistoryDownload PostCSV end. Post Response===" + strResult);

                               if (oTaskPostAsync.Result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                                   result = true;
                               else
                                   result = false;

                           });
```

Model class used same as both side with in application & same as in webApi.

```
 public class CSVItem
    {
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        public double Input1 { get; set; }
        public double Input2 { get; set; }
        public double Input3 { get; set; }
        public double Input4 { get; set; }
        public double Input5 { get; set; }
        public double Input6 { get; set; }
        public string Input7 { get; set; }
        public double Input8 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: with a name that includes "CSV" are you sure that the data being sent is properly formatted JSON?

Comment: your server requires a json object of CSVItem with a property SerialNumber, but in your client you are sending string content, either change your server to receive plain string, or change your client to send json object { "SerialNumber" : "data from client" }

Comment: Both side **CSVItem** class object are same, when i send using simple .net application everything working fine but when i'm going to send with xamarin app it always send null into CSVItem object. webapi always receive null.

Comment: Nkosi check in full code i have post simple class object & both side having same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` convert `item` to JSON, instead of using `item.ToString()`.
For example:

```
var oTaskPostAsync = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType));
```

You could refer to [Consuming a RESTful Web Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest) for more information.